# Zero-sized struct

Tags: c++

According to the C++ standard (inherited from C) empty structs have a non-zero size nevertheless. The reason for this (pitiful IMHO) is that two distinct variables should have different addresses. Now, inheriting an empty struct does not always "inflate" the object. But in some situations this is the case.

I have a pretty sophisticated classes architecture, involving fierce template voodoo. As the result the final classes (instances of which I need to create) may have several empty structs inherited. Due to this fact part of them may be inflated eventually. And the worst part is that their memory layout actually depends on the order of inheritance.

I'd like to get rid of all this, if it's possible.

Is there a C++ compiler that can be configured to eliminate this space waste, in expense of breaking the standard actually?

**Edit:**

I mean this:

```
struct Empty1 {};
struct Empty2 {};

struct NonEmpty {
    int Value;
};

struct MyClass1
    :public NonEmpty
    ,public Empty1
    ,public Empty2
{
};

struct MyClass2
    :public Empty1
    ,public NonEmpty
    ,public Empty2
{
};

struct MyClass3
    :public Empty1
    ,public Empty2
    ,public NonEmpty
{
};

STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(MyClass1) == 8);
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(MyClass2) == 4);
STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(MyClass3) == 8);
```

Not only empty structs inflate the object (when more than one such a thing inherited), but also the result depends on the order of inheritance of the empty structs.

Comment: I think you can leave C out of it as you are using templates...

Comment: The empty base optimization is expressly permitted by the language standard.  "Their memory layout actually depends on the order of inheritance" is somewhat concerning since there is no guarantee whatsoever about the location of base class subobjects.  Do you have an example of what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Have you actually demonstrated that this is a problem with your current compiler? I would expect that an empty class used as a base class would take no space in the derived class; a concrete example would be helpful.

Comment: The reason isn’t really pitiful. You just don’t really cite it; the real reason is much more sophisticated. The standard *may* have done without this restriction (I’m not sure) but this would have required a complex proof that this always leads to well-formed programs.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Not sure what you mean by "well-formed programs". From the implementation/practical perspective I see no problems with zero-sized structs. I've heard ridiculous arguments that allowing zero-sized objects actually allows you to allocate infinite number of objects "for free". All this is very, but solving those gedankenexperiments actually creates problem in real-world cases.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: I believe that standard was ok more-or-less in C, where creating zero-sized structs was something very exotic, and there was no actual need for this. However in C++ there are a lot of use cases for empty classes/structs

Comment: @James McNellis: please see my edit

Comment: The right solution here is to rework your program so that it does not depend on particular ordering, presence, and layout of base class subobjects.

Comment: @James McNellis: This is exactly what I want to achieve. I want to include all the bases in my class, so that the size of my object won't depend on subtle changes in the code, such as order of inheritance of empty bases

Comment: Changing the order of inheritance is not a subtle change.  If your type is not POD, your code should be written in such a way that it doesn't matter what order the base classes are named, or whether the EBO takes place.  When you are concerned about memory layout, you should use POD types.  For all intents and purposes, there are no guarantees for non-POD types.

Comment: @James McNellis: It's not critical for me to obey the exact memory layout. It's just I don't want unneeded memory waste. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Don't inherit from a bunch of empty classes. You can probably achieve whatever you use the empty base classes for some other way.

Comment: @user786653: I don't inherit empty classes "on purpose". It happens so during the instantiation of some template classes. (my example is just for demonstration of what goes on). Of course there are many ways to solve this, one may not use templates at all. But are there any normal solutions?

Comment: @valdo: My comment wasn't meant to be dismissive rather, since c++ doesn't allow for structs with zero size in the general case, I think you're likely to get better responses if you were more concrete in your question as there could be several "normal" approaches depending on the problem at hand.

Comment: I'm betting you're compiling under MSVC?  This is a known issue with multiple inheritance: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/100686/empty-member-optimization-not-working-properly Solutions include not worrying about it, switching to a "better" compiler, and avoiding multiple inheritance.

Comment: @Dennis Zickefoose: this makes sense. However the issue seems to be more complex. See my example. Sometimes MSVC does optimize both empty bases, but this depends on the order of their inheritance. Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @valdo Your dismissive attitude doesn’t exactly help. To see that allowing zero size objects isn’t trivial it’s enough to consider the obvious consequence: if `sizeof(T) == 0`, then how does pointer arithmetic work? How do arrays of `T` work? How do you identify objects? Say you’ve got a `T[10] a` array and you use the addresses of the objects in a `map<T*, int> m` (for whatever purpose). Then usually you would retrieve data from `m` for an object in `a` using `m[&a[i]]`. But if `sizeof(T) == 0`, this no longer works. Oops, you’ve broken C++. *Perhaps* this is solvable, but not easily.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: Still I don't see critical problems here. Arrays of `T` don't actually "work". There is a code generated by the compiler responsible to the stack reservation for automatic objects/arrays, pointer arithmetic operations related to indexing, dereferencing and etc. In case of zero-sized objects all this codes probably resolves to trivial NOP, **so what?**

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: About "indentifying" objects by their addresses, like an example with your `map` - this makes sense actually. But this is a pretty exotic scenario which can be solved separately IMHO. Either don't rely on fact that objects have unique addresses, or use `STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(T) != 0);` to verify at compile-time that your objects are not zero-sized if you're going to identify them by addresses. OTOH I'm talking here about **real-world** problems. In C++ there are a lot of use cases for zero-sized objects.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: In conclusion. I agree with you that allowing zero-sized objects may bite. But you also should agree with me that forbidding those also bites. In times of C this probably was not important, because creating zero-sized objects didn't make sense usually. But in C++ this is a real problem. I can demonstrate you some examples if you want. So, I would expect there is a way to control this behavior, which unfortunately seems not to be designed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a C++ compiler that can be configured to eliminate this space waste, ...

Yes. gcc-4.3.4

> ... in expense of breaking the standard actually?

No, the standard allows your desired behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this answers my question. Is there a special configuration needed to enable this? Is it also possible to eliminate the unneeded space for empty objects? That is, objects that consists only of empty bases.

Comment: @valdo: No, you couldn't put them in arrays (since array elements are at address that differ by `sizeof(T)`). Since you can't put a base class _subobject_ by itself in an array, it can have zero space.

Comment: @MSalters: I thought about a class that has member variables (objects) of various kinds. Some of them may eventually evaluate to empty structs.

Comment: @valdo: Member variables are yet another case, and do not fall under the base class exception. See `boost::compressed_pair` for a class that makes creative use of the base class exception

Answer (score 6):

The **Empty Base Optimization** is what will allow an empty base to not "inflate" the object, as you call it. However, you must be careful so that an object does not inherit from the same empty base twice or this optimization won't be allowed. A way to avoid this is to template the empty bases, instantiating them so that no same empty template instantiation will be inherited more than once.

If your base classes are used to tag concrete classes, then you could consider changing your design to a non-intrusive one.

Answer (score 5):

You will find, in most modern c++ compilers that:

```
struct a { }; // empty struct
struct b : a { int x}; // inherits from empty struct.

assert(sizeof(b)==sizeof(int)); // despite sizeof(a) >0
```

Does that, practically, assuage your concerns?

Comment: +1 just because valdo could easily write some tests to make sure the optimization is being made.

Comment: @Chris: That is actually *required* by [C++11's standard layout rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType). It's only when you have multiple objects with NSDMs that a problem appears.

Answer (score 1):

g++ supports zero size arrays, you can use one of:

```
struct Empty1 {
  int dummy[0];
};
```

or

```
struct Empty2 {
  int dummy[];
};
```

It generates warning, only if the '-pedantic' flags is used.

Comment: Is there any reading about this gem in a standard or somewhere? How portable is it?

Answer (score 1):

C++20 now has the `[[no_unique_address]]` attribute (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/attributes/no_unique_address). Use it on member variables that are empty structs.

For example :

```cpp
struct empty {};
struct x {
    int blee;
    [[no_unique_address]] empty e;
};
static_assert(sizeof(x) == 4);
```

Answer (score 0):

A base class can be of non-zero size if, as you already stated, it would otherwise have the same address as another instance of the same type in the same object.

To "solve" this problem, you need to ensure that the empty classes or structs you inherit another class from do not have any ancestors in common.

Or you can manually lay out the class yourself, but it sounds like you are doing something like creating a DirectX vertex type from the DirectX vertex declaration enumeration, so that wouldn't really help.